# What is the fastest way to load the first row of 2x4 64b structure into a 256b register at AVX2?

Tags: c++, simd, hpc, avx2

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct HorStruct {
    uint64_t v[2][4];
    typedef uint64_t value_type;
    typedef uint64_t* iterator;
    typedef const uint64_t* const_iterator;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef uint64_t* pointer;
    typedef const uint64_t* const_pointer;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;};
```

I am wondering how can I load its first row into a _m256i variable on AVX2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `_mm256_load_si256` intrinsic. Quoting the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/):

> __m256i _mm256_load_si256 (__m256i const * mem_addr)
>
> `#include "immintrin.h"`
>
> [...]
>   *Description* Load 256-bits of integer data from memory into dst.
>   mem_addr must be aligned on a 32-byte boundary or a general-protection
>   exception may be generated.

If the alignment requirement is a problem, you can use the unaligned version `_mm256_loadu_si256`. Note however that aligned loads may be significantly faster.

Comment: Can I use it like : _m256i loc = _mm256_load_si256 (Horstruct.v[0]) ?

Comment: @user1979163 You will probably need to cast the pointer for it to compile: `__m256i loc = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(hs.v));`.

Comment: On recent Intel HW, if the address *is* aligned, `movdqu` will have the same latency as `movdqa`.  Also, as long as the load doesn't split a cacheline (or worse, a page boundary), there's almost no penalty for unaligned loads.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Thanks for your answer. Do you have any advice for  doing the reverse operation? 2x 256b registers to 2x4 64b structure?

Comment: @YigitDemirag The corresponding intrinsic would be `_mm256_store_si256`. You should familiarize yourself with the Intrinsics Guid linked in the original answer. It's quite useful for tackling these kinds of questions.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Yes, you're right. But my main problem is I don't know how to put this register values into a specific row of a matrix in a vectorized way. I think I should use some casting as you suggest before, right?

Comment: @YigitDemirag Just make sure the pointers point to the correct place and then cast for the store to keep the compiler happy. Like `uint64_t v[2][4]; __m256 r1, r2; _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(v[0]), r1); _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(v[1]), r2);`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Thanks a lot. I figured it out a couple of seconds ago :)